# Laravel - unable to get value from Google pie chart listener

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, request, pie-chart

In here I need to get the `PieSliceText` of the **Google pie chart**.

I have added an `listener` to get the value from pie chart selection. In my case that method return only the `percentage` of that selected part of the 'pie chart'. Below is the code:

**index.blade.php**

```
function load_chart_data() 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('getCatWiseSummery') }}", // provide correct url
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON', 
        success: function(chart_values) 
        {   
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);
          var options = {
                     'width':650,
                     'height':550,
                  };
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('catwiseChart'));
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select',   function(){console.log(this.getSelection().focusNode.data);});

          chart.draw(data, options);         

              }
          });
}
```

this `console.log(this.getSelection().focusNode.data);` line returns the selected `pieSlice percentage`. Instead of that `percentage` I need to return the selected `pieSliceText label` of that selection.

Comment: It may be in the event agrument. The documentation doesn't bother mentioning what is passed but you could log it: `addListener(chart, 'select', function(){console.log('arguments:',arguments)`

Comment: what ever the first argument, I need to get 'this.getSelection().focusNode.label.text)' instead of 'this.getSelection().focusNode.data)' without any calculation process. Because .... 'focusNode.data' returns the percentage value of the selection.

Comment: The event should have information about the node you clicked, my guess is that both node and data are in there. The value of `this` could be the whole chart (although the node clicked would have arguably been better) but you are only interested in the thing you clicked, that's usually found in the event. Like native click event gives you `event.target` (=element clicked) and `event.currentTarget` (=current element when bubbling).